# Capture Praat error messages resulting from sendpraat command in Python

Tags: python, windows, ctypes, praat

You can start an instance of Praat and then use `sendpraat.exe` to send GUI commands to it. So, if you have Praat running in the background, the following command will cause it to read in a local `mysound.wav` file as a Sound object:

```
sendpraat praat "Read from file... mysound.wav"
```

And there are a bunch of ways to send this command via Python, e.g.:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('sendpraat praat "Read from file... mysound.wav"')
```

But if `mysound.wav` doesn't exist, the Praat instance will pop up a message box with the error. How can I capture the contents of this error message in Python and avoid the popup?

These solutions don't work for the problem:

1. For this particular example, I could just check in Python if the file exists. But I also need to deal with all of the other errors that Praat will throw, such as when it has trouble with encodings, or when samples are clipped.
2. I can use `nocheck` before the command (`sendpraat praat nocheck "Read from file... mysound.wav"` to avoid the popup, but then Python has no way of knowing that the command failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nocheck` is the only way in Praat to do error handling, limited though it may be. If you want to use the GUI programmatically from Python (or any other such), the best way to do error handling is to use `nocheck` and then catch errors by looking for the side effects of those commands.

If you are opening a `Sound`, you can do `assert numberOfSelected("Sound")` or something like that (with more or less elegant tests). If you are writing something to disk, you can use `fileReadable()` to see if the file was created.

Alternatively, if you are not actually *using* the GUI, you can bypass `sendpraat` entirely and use Praat through the console (with versions before 6.0 a different binary called `praatcon` was needed for Windows, but more recent versions use the same program with the `--run` option).

You won't be able to pass commands directly to it, but you can encapsulate those commands into scripts and then just do `subprocess.call('praat --run path/to/my/script.praat arguments')` or something like that. Then you might be able to catch errors in that script (= your commands) using Python, or implement the same manual error checking as above.

#### Update: an example

Here's an example (in Perl, and in Linux, but you get the idea):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Capture::Tiny ':all';
use Try::Tiny;

try {
  ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture {
    system( 'praat', '--run', '~/stdout.praat' );
  }
}
catch {
  chomp;
  warn "It died: $_";
};

print "STDOUT:\n$stdout\n";
print "STDERR:\n$stderr";
```

And the contents of `stdout.praat`:

```
abc$ = "abcde"
num$ = "0123456789"
writeInfoLine: abc$
assert selected("Sound")  ; Fail
writeInfoLine: abc$, num$ ; Won't run
```

The output:

```
user@linux:~$ perl stdout.pl
STDOUT:
abcde

STDERR:
Error: No Sound selected.
Formula not run.
Script line 4 not performed or completed:
« assert selected("Sound") ; Fail »
Script “/home/user/stdout.praat” not completed.
Praat: command file “/home/user/stdout.praat” not completed.
```

#### Update: try / catch in Praat

Since I wrote this answer, I've managed to implement a very rudimentary version of [a try/catch procedure for Praat](http://cpran.net/docs/plugins/utils/#try). With it, a script like

```
include path/to/try.proc

writeInfoLine: "Before fail"

call try
  ... abc$ = "abcde"                                \n
  ... num$ = "0123456789"                           \n
  ... Create Sound as pure tone: "tone",            \n
  ...   ... 1, 0, 0.4, 44100, 440, 0.2, 0.01, 0.01  \n
  ... assert selected("TextGrid")  ; Fail           \n
  ... Remove                       ; Won't run      \n

if try.catch
  appendInfoLine: "Failed!"
endif
```

will execute without crashing, leaving behind the Sound that was created because the line where it is removed did not run.

The procedure is available in the [utils](http://cpran.net/plugins/utils) plugin distributed through CPrAN, and is implemented [here](https://gitlab.com/cpran/plugin_utils/blob/master/procedures/try.proc).

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to send Praat errors to stderr or something like that? I like the `praatcon` solution but it means running a new instance of Praat for every run of the script.

Comment: Praat (and Praatcon) should print its errors to `STDERR` (although of course, it'll do so right before it dies). Up until recently, a bug in Praatcon meant that printing to `STDOUT` or `STDERR` [would not work](https://uk.groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/praat-users/conversations/messages/7380), but that was fixed with [5.4.13](https://github.com/praat/praat/releases/tag/v5.4.13). I'll update my answer with an example of how you can work this, but be warned: it won't be Python.

Comment: Depending on what your task is, you might be able to reduce the number of times praat is run by including part of the logic of your larger script into the praat script. This won't work every time, but it's something.